# Trouble interpreting "if (result1) *result1 = t2" statement in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm not a C programmmer but I am translating a C program to Delphi.  All is going well except I can't figure out the meaning of statements like this one:

```
if (result1)
    *result1 = t2;
```

It seems that the assignment is always to be performed and then tested for some condition?

The complete C program is listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ATrilateration if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

In C, there is an assimilation between integers and booleans: any number not zero means true. In C 99 the `bool` type was added (following the steps of C++), but these so common uses are difficult to erradicate (and there is also a lot of legacy source code using this convention).

The true meaning of that sentence is:

```
if ( result1 != NULL ) {
    *result1 = t2;
}
```

This means that `result1` is a pointer, and if the probable memory allocation previous to this line was successful, then it is used to store the value `t2`.

So, what does this have to do with pointers? Well, a pointer is basically an integer (a memory address), and NULL is (very commonly, but not always) zero. So "result1" can be interpreted as `result1 != NULL` or even `result1 != 0`.

Finally `NULL` is returned when a memory allocation (or any other memory operation) was unsuccessful, so it is quite common to test that the pointer is alive (i.e., it is not `NULL`) before using it.

Answer (score 2):

it tests if the pointer `result1` is not `null`. If `true` `t2` will be assigned as value of `result1`

Comment: Not quite, you missed the asterisk.

Comment: @JeremyP: I did not miss it. That is why I wrote `t2` will be assigned to the **value** of `result1` and not to the **address** of it.

Comment: The value of `result1` is a *pointer* i.e. the address.  What the statement does is assign `t2` to the value of the variable obtained by dereferencing `result1`.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ it is **Undefined Behavior** to dereference a `NULL` pointer. In short really bad things can happen if you do so.

So it is always a good practice to check a pointer for `NULL` before dereferencing it.
The said code does that.

Answer (score 1):

result looks like a pointer to a pointer. if it's not null, point the pointer it's pointing to to t2.

if result1 is not null result1 points to an address
 point that address to t2

Answer (score 0):

```
if (result1 != NULL)
{
    *result1 = t2;
}
```

If result1 is a `null` pointer, the line `*result = t2` should cause a SEGFAULT.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a common pattern in C, if you want to pass return results through function parameters.  There are no `var` parameters in C functions, so you simulate the idea by passing a *pointer* to the value as a parameter and then the function can set the value by assigning to the place pointed to by the pointer.

The line in `main` that looks like this:

```
result = trilateration(&o1, &o2, p1, r1, p2, r2, p3, r3, MAXZERO);
```

creates pointers that point to the address in memory of the variables o1 and o2 (that's what the `&` means).  Then the line in the function

```
*result1 = t2;
```

assigns `t2` to whatever `result1` is pointing to, which in this case is `o1`.

The line

```
if (result1)
```

tests if the pointer is "true" (false is the same as 0 and any non zero value is true in C ), so it is the same as

```
if (result1 != NULL)  // NULL is effectively the same as 0.
```

The reason this is done is so that it is legal to pass NULL as the first argument of the function.  You might want to do this if you are only interested in getting one of the two result values.  So, you can safely do

```
result = trilateration(NULL, &o2, p1, r1, p2, r2, p3, r3, MAXZERO);
```

if you don't care about calculating `o1`.

Answer (score 0):

`result1` is a pointer; its value is the location of another object in memory.

In C boolean contexts, a zero-valued integral expression evaluates as `false`, whereas any non-zero-valued integral expression evaluates as `true`.  In a pointer context, a zero-valued integral expression is treated as the *NULL pointer constant*, which represents a well-defined "nowhere" and is considered an invalid pointer value.

So `if (result1)` tests the value of the pointer; if it's 0, that means `result1` isn't pointing anywhere meaningful, and since 0 also means `false`, the body of the `if` statement won't be executed.  It's a shorthand way of writing `if (result1 != NULL)`.  If the value isn't 0, then it's a valid pointer value (hopefully; see below), the test passes, and the expression `*result1 = t2` writes the value of `t2` to the location *pointed to* by `result1`.

Couple of notes about pointers: first of all, a non-NULL pointer value isn't necessarily a *valid* pointer, in that its value may not correspond to the address of a live object.  The behavior on attempting to *dereference* (access the memory pointed to by) an invalid pointer is undefined; your program may crash outright, or it may continue to execute in a bad state, or it may work just fine.  Thus it's usually considered good practice to initialize all pointers to NULL when they're declared, and to set them to NULL when whatever they're pointing to is no longer in use.

Secondly, while the null pointer *constant* is always zero-valued, the null pointer *value* used by the implementation doesn't have to be.  It's up to the compiler to map these values, so as far as your *source code* is concerned, NULL always means 0; just don't assume that's true for the underlying OS.